# Default value don't work in kartik datapicker dymanic form

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, yii2-advanced-app, dynamic-forms

v
The default value in the kartik datepicker is not working in dynamic form after it is reinitialize(After the new form is added),
This is for Date-of-birth, the date of birth i want to start form 23-02-1982..

```
    <?= $form->field($dir, "[{$index}]owner_dob")->widget(DatePicker::classname(), 
           [ "options" => ["placeholder" => "Date of Birth",
            "value" => "23-02-1982",],
            "id" => "dating",
            "type" => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
            "pluginOptions" => [
            "format" => "dd-mm-yyyy",
            "endDate" => date("d-m-Y"),
            "autoclose"=>true,
            ]])->label(false);?>
```

Im using wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget, for dynamic form. all fields are coming properly except this datepicker.
After i reinitialize i get blank field, and the starting date is today's date.

This is the js code im using for reinitialize..

```
  $this->registerJs(<<<JS
          $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on('afterInsert', function(e, item) {
          var datePickers = $(this).find('[data-krajee-kvdatepicker]');
          datePickers.each(function(index, el) {
          $(this).parent().removeData().kvDatepicker('remove');
          $(this).parent().kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));
          });
          });
          JS
          , \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

Reinitialize is happening but its coming blank fields and showing current date.

Comment: What is Kartik DatePicker?

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker. This is datepicker extension for yii2